# Magento Admin Backend Blank Page after disabling Mage_ extension accidentally

Tags: magento

I was disabling the extensions one by one to check a problem, but accidentally disabled some of the core extensions. Immediately the backend went blank and so I tried to enable all the extensions that I disabled in `etc/modules`. After that I cleared everything inside `var` folder but it was still not working.

So I copied the whole of `etc/modules` folder to replace but it still doesn't work after clearing `cache` by deleting `cache` folder.

Then I copied `app` folder and change `local.xml`, but it still doesn't work.

How can I restore back my admin page?

My Magento Version is `1.7`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled modules from Magento Backend or by editing the files under etc/modules directory.

Comment: @RohitS i disabled them from magento backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have disabled the modules from backend you need to enable it directly from database.The table core_config_data holds the data whether the module is enabled/disabled.Execute the below query and it will list all the available modules

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output/%'
```

Now choose the appropriate row and set the value to 0.

Comment: The query only lists the modules .You need to edit the value column and set value as 0 for those whose value is 1

Comment: Let me just try again